# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80 (unusual occurrence))

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

This is a strange problem. I have an asmx web servervice that implements  about 20 methods. I have recently added a new method and this fails with

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80

All the other methods still function correctly.

The method works fine locally.

You can call the mehod directly by the url from the client machine and it will return the required xml. As soon as it is called from the client via the application it fails.

What I find confusing is the reference to 127.0.0.0:80 when the service is hosted on 192.168.60.70.

> [SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80]
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +239
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) +35
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +224
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +1878753
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +13
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +103
>   Sis.SiDem.Ocm.PL.OCM.OCM.GetFields() in c:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Si-Dem 1 OCM\workspace\Sis.SiDem.Ocm.PL\Web References\OCM\Reference.cs:646
>   _12_002_OCM_Presentation_Logic.ChallengePage.GetFieldDefinitions() in c:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Si-Dem 1 OCM\workspace\Sis.SiDem.Ocm.PL\ChallengePage.cs:298
>   _12_002_OCM_Presentation_Logic.ChallengePage.ProcessChallengePage() in c:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Si-Dem 1 OCM\workspace\Sis.SiDem.Ocm.PL\ChallengePage.cs:307
>   SIS.CaseManagement.PresentationLayer.Challenge.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Si-Dem 1 OCM\workspace\Sis.SiDem.Ocm.PL.KensingtonAndChelsea\Challenge.aspx.cs:34
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

I assume somehing is amiss when posted the request for this specific soap method but I can't find where - does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: posting the relevant function code might help

Comment: According to what I am assuming, It might be your hosting environment is recycling sessions (and I would guess you are using IIS since you are using asp.net)

You might want to review your application pool settings.

If you are running this as a instance of IIS express, then the "web server" visual studio spawns might also be timing out and closing, causing the service to be unreachable

Comment: "reference to 127.0.0.0:80 when the service is hosted on 192.168.60.70." Ok, but it does not matter where you host the service. What matters is the endpoint set for the web service on the client. It is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:80, therefore, what is your endpoint configuration on the client for the service? Is it getting the endpoint from default values?